# CMAKE building static executable instead of using dynamic library

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking, dynamic-linking

My cmake file is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(libtry CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(EXE_NAME libtry)

file(GLOB_RECURSE MAIN_SRC_FILES "src/*.cpp")
add_library (Try SHARED ${MAIN_SRC_FILES})


set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(${EXE_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${EXE_NAME} Try)
```

This file works and creates the two files: a .so file and an executable and it works perfectly. The problem is even after removing the .so file, the executable is working normally which means that the executable is statically linked.

Why this is happening and why cmake is not dynamically using the .so file?

**Update**
The dependencies by running `ldd` confirms this. Output of ldd is

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffea5fe000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3585779000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3585563000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f358519c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3584e96000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3585aa7000)
```

Comment: Check the output of `ldd` run on your executable.  It will tell you what dynamic libraries it depends on, and the location of the libraries it finds to resolve those dependencies.

Comment: Why does your executable have the name "libtry"? This conflicts with the name of your shared library

Comment: No, the library name is `libTry` where as the executable's name is `libtry`. Linux names are case sensitive

Comment: Silly question, couldn't this also mean that instead of being statically linked, the references to Try are optimized out (aka you don't call anything from libTry.so?)

Comment: Not so silly. The code in main.cpp explicitly calls the library. I made sure of that. Also the library is not so simple to be eliminated. I completely used a code for Stack.

Comment: is there an update on this? Im facing a similar problem